# My app crashes on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and S5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a basic app including 4 tabs and 2 activities in total. It works on all Android versions from 4.1 to 7 on the emulator devices. But it crashes on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and S5, but works well on other devices that I tried.

I want to have an idea what may lead it. Should I add my codes here?

Comment: You should add any relevant code, and any errors recieved. There are *always* errors.

Comment: OK thanks. I will edit the questions in minutes.

Comment: please post here error line here